# Using HighCharts and DotNet.HighCharts to "Play" Multiple Series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a set of series that I have created using VB.NET and DotNet.HighCharts:

```
Dim SeriesList4As New List(Of Series)(stfipsList4.Count)
```

What I want to have happen is something similar to http://jsfiddle.net/8M2fF/ except I want to be able to pass in multiple series without knowing before hand how many I have.

The VB code that created that example above is this:

```
        Dim stfipsList4 = (From r In dt4.AsEnumerable() Select r("areaname")).Distinct().ToList()
        Dim SeriesList4 As New List(Of Series)(stfipsList4.Count)
        Dim seriesItem4(stfipsList4.Count) As Series
        Dim xDate4 As DateTime
        Dim fakeDate4 As String
        Dim sX4 As Integer

        sX4 = 1
        For Each state In stfipsList4
            Dim data As New Dictionary(Of DateTime, Decimal)
            Dim stateVal As String = state.ToString
            Dim recCount As Integer = dt4.Rows.Count - 1
            Dim seriesPointCount As Integer = dt4.Compute("Count(population)", "areaname = '" + stateVal + "'")
            Dim chartData As Object(,) = New Object(seriesPointCount - 1, 1) {}
            Dim x As Integer = 0
            For i As Integer = 0 To recCount
                If dt4.Rows(i)("areaname").ToString = stateVal Then
                    fakeDate4 = "1/1/" + dt4.Rows(i)("periodyear").ToString
                    xDate4 = DateTime.Parse(fakeDate4)
                    chartData.SetValue(xDate4.Date, x, 0)
                    chartData.SetValue(dt4.Rows(i)("population"), x, 1)
                    x += 1
                End If

            Next

            seriesItem4(sX4) = New Series With {
                        .Name = state.ToString, _
                        .Data = New Helpers.Data(chartData)
            }

            SeriesList4.Add(seriesItem4(sX4))

            sX4 = sX4 + 1
        Next

        Dim iterateData As String = JsonSerializer.Serialize(seriesItem4(1))

            Dim chart4 As Highcharts = New Highcharts("chart4").SetOptions(New Helpers.GlobalOptions() With { _
                .[Global] = New [Global]() With { _
                        .UseUTC = False _
                    } _
                }).InitChart(New Chart() With { _
                 .DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Column, _
                 .MarginRight = 10, _
                 .Events = New ChartEvents() With { _
                  .Load = "ChartEventsLoad" _
                 } _
                }).SetTitle(New Title() With { _
                 .Text = "Population" _
                }).SetTooltip(New Tooltip() With { _
                    .Formatter = "function() { return '<b>' + this.series.name + '<br/>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.x) +'</b>: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0, ','); }" _
                }).SetXAxis(New XAxis() With { _
                 .Type = AxisTypes.Datetime, _
                 .TickPixelInterval = 150 _
                }).SetYAxis(New YAxis() With { _
                       .Min = 0, _
                       .Title = New YAxisTitle() With { _
                        .Text = "Population", _
                        .Align = AxisTitleAligns.High _
                        } _
                }).SetSeries(New Series() With { _
                     .Data = New Helpers.Data(New Object() {}) _
                }) _
                .SetOptions(New Helpers.GlobalOptions() With { _
                .Colors = palette_colors _
                }) _
                .AddJavascripVariable("iterated", iterateData.ToString) _
                .AddJavascripFunction("ChartEventsLoad", "// set up the updating of the chart each second" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                                  " var result = iterated.data;" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                                  " var counter = 0;" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                                  " var series = this.series[0];" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                                  " var loopseries = function() {" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                                  " if (counter <= result.length) {" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                                  " var p = String(result[counter]);" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                                  " var splitp = p.split("","");" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                                  " var x = Number(splitp[0]);" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                                  " var y = Number(splitp[1]);" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                                  " series.addPoint([x, y], true, series.points.length > 10, true);" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                                  " counter++;" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                                  " } else {" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                                  " clearInterval(loopseries);" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                                  " }};" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                                  " setInterval(loopseries, 300);")

        ltrChart4.Text = chart4.ToHtmlString()
```

This is just for a single series. I would like to pass in a List(Of Series).
Things that need to be involved:
Creating n number of series
Adding points to each series
Naming each series

I can handle those items it is just passing in the master series "list" that I cannot accomplish.

EDIT:
There seems to be some confusion on what I am asking. I am able to pass N number of series to HighCharts via the DotNet.HighCharts API. What I am not currently able to do is pass this same set of series to the javascript function to loop through and "play" the series. Please see:

```
            .AddJavascripVariable("iterated", iterateData.ToString) _
            .AddJavascripFunction("ChartEventsLoad", "// set up the updating of the chart each second" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                              " var result = iterated.data;" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                              " var counter = 0;" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                              " var series = this.series[0];" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                              " var loopseries = function() {" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                              " if (counter <= result.length) {" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                              " var p = String(result[counter]);" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                              " var splitp = p.split("","");" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                              " var x = Number(splitp[0]);" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                              " var y = Number(splitp[1]);" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                              " series.addPoint([x, y], true, series.points.length > 10, true);" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                              " counter++;" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                              " } else {" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                              " clearInterval(loopseries);" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                              " }};" & vbCr & vbLf & _
                              " setInterval(loopseries, 300);")
```

The .AddJavaScriptVariable expects a string and in-lining the code is giving me invalid object references.

Answer (score 5):

I actually use DotNet.Highcharts to create a chart that has an undefined number of series.  To do this I query for the data I need to add to the chart using linq.  I use a list of object[] to create the individual points then I take that list and add it to a list of Series.  I iterate through the loop as many times as I need to get all of the Series.  Then for SetSeries I assign what was contained in the Series list.  The code is written in C# but I am sure you can change it to VB.NET.  Here is the entire ActionResult I use for creating the chart:

```
public ActionResult CombinerBarToday(DateTime? utcStartingDate = null,
                                     DateTime? utcEndingDate = null)
{
    //GET THE GENERATED POWER READINGS FOR THE SPECIFIED DATETIME
    var firstQ = from s in db.PowerCombinerHistorys
                 join u in db.PowerCombiners on s.combiner_id equals u.id
                 where s.recordTime >= utcStartingDate
                 where s.recordTime <= utcEndingDate
                 select new
                 {
                     CombinerID = u.name,
                     Current = s.current,
                     RecordTime = s.recordTime,
                     Voltage = s.voltage,
                     Watts = (s.current * s.voltage)
                 };

    //GET A LIST OF THE COMBINERS CONTAINED IN THE QUERY
    var secondQ = (from s in firstQ
                   select new
                   {
                        Combiner = s.CombinerID
                   }).Distinct();

    /* THIS LIST OF SERIES WILL BE USED TO DYNAMICALLY ADD AS MANY SERIES 
     * TO THE HIGHCHARTS AS NEEDED WITHOUT HAVING TO CREATE EACH SERIES INDIVIUALY */
    List<Series> allSeries = new List<Series>();

    TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

    //LOOP THROUGH EACH COMBINER AND CREATE SERIES
    foreach (var distinctCombiner in secondQ)
    {
        var combinerDetail = from s in db2.PowerCombinerHistorys
                 join u in db2.PowerCombiners on s.combiner_id equals u.id
                 where u.name == distinctCombiner.Combiner
                 where s.recordTime >= utcStartingDate
                 where s.recordTime <= utcEndingDate
                 select new
                 {
                     CombinerID = u.name,
                     Current = s.current,
                     RecordTime = s.recordTime,
                     Voltage = s.voltage,
                     Watts = (s.current * s.voltage) / 1000d
                 };


        var results = new List<object[]>();

        foreach (var detailCombiner in combinerDetail)
        {
            results.Add(new object[] { 
                            TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(detailCombiner.RecordTime, easternZone), 
                            detailCombiner.Watts });
        }

        allSeries.Add(new Series
        {
            Name = distinctCombiner.Combiner,
            //Data = new Data(myData)
            Data = new Data(results.ToArray())

        });
    }

    Highcharts chart = new Highcharts("chart")
    .InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Spline, ZoomType = ZoomTypes.X})
    .SetTitle(new Title { Text = "Combiner History" })
    .SetSubtitle(new Subtitle { Text = "Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in" })
    .SetOptions(new GlobalOptions { Global = new Global { UseUTC = false } })
    .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
    {
        Spline = new PlotOptionsSpline
        {
            LineWidth = 2,
            States = new PlotOptionsSplineStates { Hover = new PlotOptionsSplineStatesHover { LineWidth = 3 } },
            Marker = new PlotOptionsSplineMarker
            {
                Enabled = false,
                States = new PlotOptionsSplineMarkerStates
                {
                    Hover = new PlotOptionsSplineMarkerStatesHover
                    {
                        Enabled = true,
                        Radius = 5,
                        LineWidth = 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
    .SetXAxis(new XAxis
    {
        Type = AxisTypes.Datetime,
        Labels = new XAxisLabels
        {
            Rotation = -45,
            Align = HorizontalAligns.Right,
            Style = "font: 'normal 10px Verdana, sans-serif'"
        },
        Title = new XAxisTitle { Text = "Time(Hour)" },
    })
    .SetYAxis(new YAxis
    {
        Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = "Kilowatt" }
    })

    .SetSeries(allSeries.Select(s => new Series {Name = s.Name, Data = s.Data }).ToArray());

    return PartialView(chart);
}
```

Comment: I have no problem getting a list of series. That is what my For 'Each state In stfipsList4' is doing. And I can iterate through that list to add the series to the chart no problem using the default method. What this question is for is to animate/play the series through time (not to be confused with the HighCharts default loading animation). See my jsFiddle for what I was trying to accomplish but with only 1 series. My problem is that I am not sure how to pass the list of series to the javascript function that iterates and does the series.addpoint.

Comment: I understand that this answer is great general solution to adding multiple series to HighCharts using the DotNet.HighCharts API but it does not address the question asked. What this does is just add all the series in the list of series at once to the chart. It does not play the series points as described in the example jsFiddle.

Comment: I originally mis-read your question. I am sorry.  I don't know why people are up-voting it.  It is a good way of using DotNet.Highcharts.  But as you mentioned it does not answer your question.