# Highcharts toggle between multiple datasets

Tags: highcharts, dataset, toggle

I've just started looking into this awesome tool and I have a few question. Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/edge/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/

```js
$(function () {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares. January, 2015 to May, 2015'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Click the columns to view versions. Source: <a href="http://netmarketshare.com">netmarketshare.com</a>.'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category'
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Total percent market share'
            }

        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '{point.y:.1f}%'
                }
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: [{
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                y: 56.33,
                drilldown: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'
            }, {
                name: 'Chrome',
                y: 24.03,
                drilldown: 'Chrome'
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                y: 10.38,
                drilldown: 'Firefox'
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                y: 4.77,
                drilldown: 'Safari'
            }, {
                name: 'Opera',
                y: 0.91,
                drilldown: 'Opera'
            }, {
                name: 'Proprietary or Undetectable',
                y: 0.2,
                drilldown: null
            }]
        }],
        drilldown: {
            series: [{
                name: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                id: 'Microsoft Internet Explorer',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v11.0',
                        24.13
                    ],
                    [
                        'v8.0',
                        17.2
                    ],
                    [
                        'v9.0',
                        8.11
                    ],
                    [
                        'v10.0',
                        5.33
                    ],
                    [
                        'v6.0',
                        1.06
                    ],
                    [
                        'v7.0',
                        0.5
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Chrome',
                id: 'Chrome',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v40.0',
                        5
                    ],
                    [
                        'v41.0',
                        4.32
                    ],
                    [
                        'v42.0',
                        3.68
                    ],
                    [
                        'v39.0',
                        2.96
                    ],
                    [
                        'v36.0',
                        2.53
                    ],
                    [
                        'v43.0',
                        1.45
                    ],
                    [
                        'v31.0',
                        1.24
                    ],
                    [
                        'v35.0',
                        0.85
                    ],
                    [
                        'v38.0',
                        0.6
                    ],
                    [
                        'v32.0',
                        0.55
                    ],
                    [
                        'v37.0',
                        0.38
                    ],
                    [
                        'v33.0',
                        0.19
                    ],
                    [
                        'v34.0',
                        0.14
                    ],
                    [
                        'v30.0',
                        0.14
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Firefox',
                id: 'Firefox',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v35',
                        2.76
                    ],
                    [
                        'v36',
                        2.32
                    ],
                    [
                        'v37',
                        2.31
                    ],
                    [
                        'v34',
                        1.27
                    ],
                    [
                        'v38',
                        1.02
                    ],
                    [
                        'v31',
                        0.33
                    ],
                    [
                        'v33',
                        0.22
                    ],
                    [
                        'v32',
                        0.15
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Safari',
                id: 'Safari',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v8.0',
                        2.56
                    ],
                    [
                        'v7.1',
                        0.77
                    ],
                    [
                        'v5.1',
                        0.42
                    ],
                    [
                        'v5.0',
                        0.3
                    ],
                    [
                        'v6.1',
                        0.29
                    ],
                    [
                        'v7.0',
                        0.26
                    ],
                    [
                        'v6.2',
                        0.17
                    ]
                ]
            }, {
                name: 'Opera',
                id: 'Opera',
                data: [
                    [
                        'v12.x',
                        0.34
                    ],
                    [
                        'v28',
                        0.24
                    ],
                    [
                        'v27',
                        0.17
                    ],
                    [
                        'v29',
                        0.16
                    ]
                ]
            }]
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

1. how can I load more data sets to this type of chart (and also hide them, so later I can toggle between them)?
2. by default if you have more series in the legend, clicking on one of them will add/remove that series. 
   but how can you toggle between sets? so only the clicked data set is visible the other(s) are hidden.
3. is it possible to load more data sets to the drilldown section?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio, I have found that using [DotNet.Highcharts](http://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/) is a very useful addition.  It allows you to program Highcharts without having to write the java script.

If that is the case then the answer I had [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250876/using-highcharts-and-dotnet-highcharts-to-play-multiple-series/10262718#10262718) may be of interest to you.  I create a Highchart with an undetermined number of Series. You could add the drilldown option inside the brackets of

```
allSeries.Add(new Series
```